# handling input in prolog with read()

Tags: prolog, dcg

I am using read() to take in user input. I planned that my program would accept input in the form of

```
a,b,c,d,e
```

and then I would convert that into a list of the elements. But doing a test in prolog i got this

```
26 ?- read(X).
|: abc,def,ghi,jkl.
X = (abc, def, ghi, jkl).
```

I am not sure, but is this returning a structure? What can I do to convert this into a list?

Comment: Sorry, but the link seems to be dead..

Comment: fixed broken link: [read line to atomic list in prolog](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7777991/read-line-to-atomic-list-in-prolog)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(abc, def, ghi, jkl) is a term with functor ',' and arity 2. You can use term inspection predicates like (=..)/2, functor/3, arg/3 etc. to decompose it, or try write_canonical/1:

```
?- T = (abc, def, ghi, jkl), write_canonical(T).
','(abc,','(def,','(ghi,jkl)))
T = (abc, def, ghi, jkl).
```

To convert such tuples to lists, you can use a DCG:

```
tuple_list((A,B)) --> !, tuple_list(A), tuple_list(B).
tuple_list(A)     --> [A].
```

Example:

```
?- T = (abc, def, ghi, jkl), phrase(tuple_list(T), Ls).
T = (abc, def, ghi, jkl),
Ls = [abc, def, ghi, jkl].
```

Comment: Thank you a million times, exactly what i was looking for. During my searches, I came across the DCG term, but never found an actual example. Again, THNAK YOU

Answer (score 0):

X = (abc, def, ghi, jkl).

That is a set of symbols; prolog doesn't recognize non-types(int,long,double,...).

A list is represented by a head(first element) and a tail(the remaining elements).
Try running the following examples:

```
   ?- [1,2,3,4,5,6]=[Head|Tail].
   ?- [1,2,3,4,5,6]=[First,Second|Tail].
```

Now you need to get familiarized with recursion(it is the heart of prologue). 
An insertion procedure might look like:

```
   insert(X, List, [X|List]).
```

But what if the list is empty; our procedure thinks that list is not so we need another procedure to suffice the previous:

```
   insert(X, [], [X|]).
```

We can do more: for instance check if an item is present within a list:

```
   present(Item,[Item|_]).
   present(Item,[_|Tail]) :-
     present(Item,Tail).
```

Notice the recursion in our last procedure: present(Item, Tail) - this recursively checks the head of the list with the variable Item which can be read from the keyboard:

```
   check_if_present :- read(X), present(X, List).
```

where List has been created at an earlier point.

We can also concatenate lists very easily:

```
     concatenating([],List,List).
     concatenating([Head|Tail],List,[Head|ResultedTail]) :-
      concatenating(Tail,List,ResultedTail).
```